# Background-position not working

Tags: html, css, background, background-position

I have a weird issue using `background-position`.. Simply it's not working !

Here's my code :

```
<div id="follow-wrapper">
    <p>Follow Us</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="facebook-img"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="twitter-img"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="googlplus-img"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="linkedin-img"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="youtube-img"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="rss-img"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#follow-wrapper ul li {
    display: inline-block;    
    margin-left:8px;    
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url('../img/follow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#facebook-img{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#twitter-img {
    background-position: 0px -26px;
}

#googleplus-img{
    background-position: 0px -52px;
}

#linkedin-img{
    background-position: 0px -78px;
}

#youtube-img{
    background-position: 0px -104px;
}

#rss-img{
    background-position: 0px -130px;
}
```

And here's the result : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ids on the `li` tags instead of the anchors.  Currently the `li` tag receives part of the necessary styling such as `width`, `background-image`, etc...  While the anchor tag receives the other piece of the styling, the background positioning.  All of these styles should be applied to the `li`.

```
<div id="follow-wrapper">
    <p>Follow Us</p>
    <ul>
        <li id="facebook-img"><a href="#" ></a></li>
        <li id="twitter-img"><a href="#" ></a></li>
        <li id="googlplus-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="linkedin-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="youtube-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="rss-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` links don't have a background on them. You need to move the ID's to the `<li>` elements. You're not targeting the right element with your CSS at the moment.

I.E.

```
<div id="follow-wrapper">
    <p>Follow Us</p>
    <ul>
        <li id="facebook-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="twitter-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="googlplus-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="linkedin-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="youtube-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="rss-img"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```